# Change UIImage ratio to fb cover in iphone Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I am picking an image from image picker and then i want to change ratios for that image as facebook cover. i have an image let suppose its resolution ia 640 widht and 480 height and i want to change it for facebook cover(851 pixels wide and 315 pixels tall) how will i do that programmatically in iphone
Check this [link](https://www.facebook.com/help/125379114252045/) for cover picture details
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Use this Method to Resize the image according to the given content mode, taking into account the image's orientation...

- (UIImage *)resizedImageWithContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode bounds:(CGSize)bounds
                interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {

CGFloat horizontalRatio = bounds.width / self.size.width;
CGFloat verticalRatio = bounds.height / self.size.height;
CGFloat ratio;

switch (contentMode) {
    case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
        ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
        break;

    case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
        ratio = MIN(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Unsupported content mode:  %d", contentMode];
}

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width * ratio, self.size.height * ratio);

return [self resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:quality];
```

}

and go this this link for more detail,[Resizing Uiimage in right way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) .

Comment: what will i pass in contentMode ?

Comment: UIViewContentMode Specifies how a view adjusts its content when its size changes.
typedef enum {
   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
   UIViewContentModeRedraw,
   UIViewContentModeCenter,
   UIViewContentModeTop,
   UIViewContentModeBottom,
   UIViewContentModeLeft,
   UIViewContentModeRight,
   UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
   UIViewContentModeTopRight,
   UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
   UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
}

Comment: apple Documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html